# Cannot start Ubuntu, critical temperature supposedly reached

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, swap, cpu, overheating

My laptop is running a dual boot setup of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 for a while now (over a year) without any issues. However, earlier today, I suspended my laptop to RAM due to low battery. Then, some hours later, I tried to start it up, but it would simply show the OS logo (Kubuntu) for a few seconds and then shut down.

While it was trying to boot, I hit `ESC` to view the output of the kernel, and I found the following output (I've included only the lines that display some sort of failure):

```
[    4.836189] CPU6: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    4.836190] CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    4.836191] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    4.836211] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    4.836213] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    4.836214] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    4.836215] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    4.836216] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    4.836217] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    4.836237] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
...
[    4.959220] thermal thermal_zone7: critical temperature reached (99 C), shutting down
...
[FAILED] Failed deactivating swap /swapfile
...
[    5.723091] systemd-shutdown[1]: Failed to wait for process: Protocol error
```

Obviously, it appears that for whatever reason my CPU is overheating and causing Ubuntu to panic and shutdown. But I am able to boot into Windows 10 with zero issues, and when I access my boot menu, the CPU is at a healthy ~50 C. Is something messed up in my kernel that is causing it to incorrectly measure the CPU temperature, or is something going seriously wrong when I try to boot into Ubuntu? Does it have something to do with Suspend to RAM? I've used it before without issue.

What should I do?

Comment: Thermal shutdown trigger occurs in the BIOS on the motherboard, not the OS. What you are seeing is the OS trying to do a clean shutdown in a hurry before BIOS cuts the power.

Comment: It could be this bug: [Kernel wrong temperature reporting](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1781924)